# Retrieving only the parent elements from firebase : Angularfire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

[image]

The image shows the structure of my database.
I want to print 1, 2 ... (so on) i.e. the parent element names alone. But couldn't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Firebase Database is essentially one JSON object.**

This object is in a tree structure. If you read from one location in the tree, you'll get each piece of data underneath it.

Take a look at this sample database.

```
{
  "items": {
    "1": {
      "title": "Hi"
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "Bye"
    }
  }
}
```

There is no way with the JavaScript SDK or AngularFire, to only read the parent keys of 1 and 2 under "items".

If you only want to read the parent keys, **you'll need to create an index** for them in the Firebase database.

```
{
  "items": {
    "1": {
      "title": "Hi"
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "Bye"
    }
  },
  "itemKeys": {
    "1": "Hi",
    "2": "Bye"
  }
}
```

Now you can create a reference at the `itemKeys` location and pass that to a `$firebaseArray()` or `$firebaseObject()`.

```
var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/itemKeys');
var syncArray = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

[If you're concerned with keeping two separate data structures consistent, check out the client-side fan-out feature.](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html)

Comment: Thanks David. That gave an idea.

Comment: No problem! If my answer worked for you please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
shallow=true
```

If you are using REST API add this to the end of your request url. Like this

```
https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/retrieving-data.json?shallow=true
```